# io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno

Tags: python, flask

i am getting io.UnsupportedOperation: fileno error in

@app.route('/view_pdf/<unique_id>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def view_pdf(unique_id):
unique_id = request.form['unique_id']
award_data = request.form.get('award_data')

```
# Map the selected data type to the corresponding table name
table_mapping = {
    '10th_data': '10th_students',
    '12th_data': '12th_students',
    'tr_data': 'teacher',
    'pr_data': 'principal',
    'scl_data': 'school'
}

if award_data in table_mapping:
    table_name = table_mapping[award_data]

    # Fetch all data from the corresponding table
    cur = db.engine.connect()
    query = f"SELECT * FROM `{table_name}` WHERE id LIKE %s"
    result = cur.execute(query, (unique_id,))
    user_data = result.fetchall()
    cur.close()

if user_data:
    # Generate image
    image_buffer = generate_filled_image(user_data)

    # Generate PDF
    pdf_buffer = generate_pdf_buffer(image_buffer)

    # Serve PDF for viewing in browser
    response = make_response(send_file(pdf_buffer, mimetype='application/pdf'))
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename={unique_id}.pdf'
    return response
else:
    return "User not found for the provided ID."
```

def generate_filled_image(user_data):
# Load the existing JPG image template
existing_image_path = 'certificate_template.jpg'
existing_image = Image.open(existing_image_path)

```
# Use the provided code for text insertion
font_type = ImageFont.truetype('static/Arima-Bold.ttf', 130)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(existing_image)
draw.text(xy=(800, 1200), text=f"{user_data[0][1]}",
          fill=(255, 69, 0), font=font_type)

# Save the new image to a BytesIO buffer
image_buffer = BytesIO()
existing_image.save(image_buffer, format='JPEG')
image_buffer.seek(0)

return image_buffer
```

def generate_pdf_buffer(image_buffer):
# Create a temporary file
with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp_file:
temp_file.write(image_buffer.read())

```
try:
    # Open the temporary file with PIL Image
    image_data = Image.open(temp_file.name)

    # Create a BytesIO buffer to save the PDF
    pdf_buffer = BytesIO()

    # Create a PDF canvas
    pdf_canvas = canvas.Canvas(pdf_buffer, pagesize=letter)

    # Draw the image onto the PDF canvas
    pdf_canvas.drawInlineImage(image_data, 0, 0)

    # Save the PDF canvas to the BytesIO buffer
    pdf_canvas.save()

    # Move the buffer cursor to the beginning
    pdf_buffer.seek(0)

    return pdf_buffer

finally:
    # Close and delete the temporary file
    temp_file.close()
    os.unlink(temp_file.name)
```

i was expecting to print something on a jpg and download in pdf

Comment: Don't forget to put triple backticks around your code so it's formatted correctly, and please share the full error stack trace. Stack traces are critical; they basically tell you where and what is going on. Was this code generated with an LLM, out of curiosity? Understanding how to debug it is good--make an attempt at it first and let us know where you're stuck exactly.